# How are head nodes of a tree determined?

Tags: syntax-trees

Below is a tree-representation of an action sequencing hierarchy, taken from Fischmeister et al 2016 (Journal Cortex).
[image]

Could anyone explain (the paper does not) by which rationale the different nodes (levels) in the tree are deemed to be either Head or Preparation?

Also, the tree seems ill-formed as the nodes at the second level from the top do not have a title/description, but only their Head/Preparation function specified.

Comment: I assume you mean the article "Self-similarity and recursion as default modes in human cognition". The tree is given as an example of a hierarchy, along with a "linguistic" hierarchy and a "social hierarchy", but there is no discussion of any of those 3 trees within the article text. So my guess is that the trees are shown as informal examples. I agree with you that it is not well-formed.

Comment: That is indeed the article, and the trees are indeed incidental to the topic of the article, and not explained. I am myself not well familiar with syntax trees so thought that a simple example such as the coffee-making one should do a good job at explaining how the node relationships are inferred - but how this tree was made seems arbitrary to me, again, unless I am ignorant about some basic aspect of syntax trees more generally...

Comment: Heads should hang down vertically, because there is only one head and one vertical line from a tree node, while there are many non-heads and many non-verticals.  (Just kidding.)

Comment: If you're talking about syntactic heads, there are different, competing criteria for defining 'heads' that lead to rather different results; see the discussion in [Zwicky (1985)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4175761).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while concerning trees and head nodes, it does not appear to be directly concerned with linguistics itself.

Comment: @curiousdannii I disagree, trees are an essential instrument for linguistics and I see many people around me who are similarly confused about the apparent arbitrariness of their logic/creation, be it in linguistics, music analysis or other fields. What I can do is edit the question to acknowledge the off-topicness but still defend the relevance of the question. Otherwise, I respectfully doubt it is worth anyone's time to spend time considering whether this question (or other borderline-relevant ones ) should be closed or not...